# Как во VueJs правильнее создать "хэлпер?"

Tags: vue.js

Есть метод генерации случайного HEX-цвета. Он будет использоваться только  в 3-5 страницах проекта. Т.е. хочется его вынести сразу в некий хелпер, чтоб по необходимости его подключить и использовать

Я решил задачу двумя способами:

- через примеси(mixin). Не нравится, что визуально не ясно, что этот метод не "тут", а "там"
- через плагин. Не нравится, что каждый раз надо писать `import Vue from 'vue'` + `Vue.use(MyPlugin)`

Т.е. по факту вопрос родился чисто из эстетических соображений: как такие вещи делаются правильнее или обычно?

PS: проект развернут на готовом шаблоне для WebPack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Командой остановились на третьем решении: импорта функций из файлов(хэлперов)
Использование:

```
import { getRandomColor, getBackgroundColor } from 'Global/helpers/colorHelper';
// .....
let color = getRandomColor();
```

**Из плюсов:**

- Нет лишних import + use как у плагина
- Визуально метод выделяется, что это взято не из `this`

**Из минусов:**

- Визуально не видно из какого хелпера этот метод. Частично решить можно с помощью алиасов при импорте. Пока не думали